# How to use textInput in Shiny to name columns of an uploaded data frame

Tags: r, shiny, textinput

I am trying to find a way to use the textInput field to allows users to indicate column names of a data frame in Shiny. A little background on the dashboard:

Dashboard allows users to upload a csv file and indicate the columns in the data frame they want to use. Then, they choose column and row names. The data they upload will then be converted into a smaller data frame that will be used for a correspondence analysis.

Everything works fine except for the column/row naming aspect. For some reason, when the program runs it assigns the text input as the name of the first row/column, and then makes the others titled "NA". I tried using strsplit() to break the text input up, but that won't work.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here is what my code and issue look like:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Perceptual Map Dashboard"),
  sidebarLayout(
# Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
    sidebarPanel(

    #Excel doc row and column names
      numericInput(inputId="startcol",label="Input start column:",value="", min=1,max=10000),
      numericInput(inputId="endcol",label="Input end column:",value="", min=1,max=10000),
    #Inputing brands and emotions
      br(),
      numericInput(inputId = "rownums",label = "How many emotions are you evaluating?",value = "", min = 1,max = 10000),
      br(),
      textInput ( 'brands', 'List the brands included in your perceptual map (separated by commas):', value=""),
      textInput ( 'emotions', 'List the emotions included in your perceptual map (separated by commas):', value=""),
    #Removing brands and emotions

    #Select graph type
      textInput(inputId="plottitle",label="Title your graph:"),
    #Upload Excel Grid
      fileInput(inputId = 'data', 'Upload CSV File',
                accept=c('.csv')),
    actionButton("go","Create Map")
    ),

# Visual Output
    mainPanel(
      wellPanel(h4('Visual')),
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot",  width = "100%", height=500), 
      downloadButton("downloadPlot", "Download Visual")
        )
      )
    )



    server <- function(input,output){



      observeEvent(input$go,{

    x <- read.csv(input$data$datapath, header = F)
    print(x)
    str(x)


    plot1 <- reactive({
    x<-x[,as.numeric(input$startcol):as.numeric(input$endcol)]
    column.sums<-colSums(x)
    print(column.sums)
    pmd.matrix<-matrix(column.sums, byrow = T, nrow=as.numeric(input$rownums))
    pmd.df2<-as.data.frame(pmd.matrix)
    # colnames(pmd.df2) = names
    # print(pmd.df2)
    # # row.names(pmd.df2)= c(as.character(input$emotions))
    print(pmd.df2)
    fit <- CA(pmd.df2, graph=F)
    K <- plot.CA(fit, col.row = "blue", col.col="black",  cex=.6,new.plot=T,
                 title=input$plottitle)
    return(K)





        })

    output$plot<- renderPlot({

          print(plot1())

      })

    output$downloadPlot2 <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "Shinyplot.png",
      content = function(file) {
        png(file)
        print(plot1)
        dev.off()
      })



     })

    }



    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


ISSUE I AM SEEING: 

       c("“Burlington”", "”JC Penny”", "”Kohls”", "”TJ Maxx”", "”Marshalls”", "”Nordstrom Rack”", "”Old Navy”", "”Target”", "”Walmart”", "”Macys”", "”Amazon”", "”Nordstrom”", "”Ross”")
    1                                                                                                                                                                                113
    2                                                                                                                                                                                113
    3                                                                                                                                                                                 69
    4                                                                                                                                                                                 55
    5                                                                                                                                                                                 91
    6                                                                                                                                                                                 73
    7                                                                                                                                                                                106
    8                                                                                                                                                                                 77
    9                                                                                                                                                                                 76
    10                                                                                                                                                                                80
    11                                                                                                                                                                                58
    12                                                                                                                                                                                86
        NA  NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA NA
    1   63  78 87 68 67 33 57  67  87 96  77 41
    2  123 100 71 70 50 77 67  93  33 44  35 36
    3   93  84 68 56 79 44 41  41 129 40 132 38
    4   43  51 62 63 59 50 58 109  70 82  66 27
    5  105  91 65 79 51 70 49  67  40 56  34 36
    6   69  71 89 66 55 68 83  51  39 67  34 44
    7   53  61 46 59 53 76 53  80  39 65  32 30
    8   55  55 52 61 63 48 85  70  57 97  60 32
    9   66  68 71 72 71 47 52  57  89 61  94 48
    10  61  55 60 56 52 56 39  60  37 39  33 65
    11  69  66 56 56 40 63 69  68  27 65  27 69
    12  70  66 59 61 46 73 62  72  47 86 113 63
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there may be two issues.   Firstly, I assume that the column names are defined in "brands" in the UI.   In the example, the naming is commented out, but I've created a minimal example that I think re-creates what you're seeing.

1) Defining "brands" as a comma-separated string as your textInput requests

```
brands<- "b1,b2,b3"
```

2) The other issue it looks like "names" variable isn't being defined?  Perhaps this is due to commenting-out.  It would need to be "names <- input$brands" I assume.  Here, outside of shiny environment:

```
names <- brands
```

3) Recreating the process with a minimal data.frame 'x'

```
x<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,2,3),c=c(4,3,2))
pmd.matrix <- matrix(colSums(x),byrow=T,nrow=1)
pmd.df2 <- as.data.frame(pmd.matrix)

colnames(pmd.df2) <- names
pmd.df2
```

#### The output of pmd.df2 shows that the first column is named and others are NA as in your example

`> pmd.df2
  b1,b2,b3 NA NA
1        6  6  9`

#### The reason is that the input$names is a string variable and so there's only one value.  It needs to be split.  Below using strsplit() which will return a list() object that can be unlist() to return a vector of objects to name, with a fix as follows:

```
names <- unlist(strsplit(brands,","))
colnames(pmd.df2) <- names
pmd.df2
```

And returning result of named columns:

`> pmd.df2
  b1 b2 b3
1  6  6  9`

Comment: This is awesome, thanks so much, Soren! This works. Apologies for the commenting out by the way, I had done that during the debugging phase to see if everything else was working. This now works perfectly. Looks like my biggest issue was the "unlist" portion. I really appreciate it!

Comment: One other question if you know the answer. The app is now working perfectly when run locally, although for some reason, the plot is not rendering when launched to shinyapps.io. Do you know why it would not appear when launched but does appear locally?

Comment: Andrew, great that the app is progressing!  There are many reasons for the local vs remote issue.  RStudio has a few articles, such as this one: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/231249288-Why-does-my-app-work-locally-but-not-on-my-Shiny-Server-   here it highlights issues around filenames, which may be in your case here.  It looks like you're taking the file name from input here: x <- read.csv(input$data$datapath, header = F) and the input file path may not match the remote file path.  This is a good starting point to check that the data is being loaded correctly.

Comment: Hmmm... I checked my logs on shiny and it looks like the CSV is loading fine since I can see that it is creating the data frame for plotting with no problem. However, it looks like the plot is getting stopped. I have all the packages uploaded, so I'm guessing maybe it's because I'm plotting within a observeEvent which I know isn't best practice. I'm going to investigate this some more and will post an update!

Comment: It's quite likely because it's not coming out of renderPlot() which will enclose various HTML functionality to support it.  Overall, you should consider moving the data frame into a reactiveVal or reactiveValues.  Alternatively, instead of observeEvent() you might consider 'K <- eventReactive(input$... {( ... }) and data management things.  And then eventReactive will return reactive value function K() that output$plot could listen to and simply return with output$plot <- renderPlot({ K() })

Comment: Hmm. I rejiggered things and that still won't work. I will try to save it as an image file to my WWW folder and then reference it with a tags$img. In any event, I am pulling the thread too far away from the initial ask so I will close it off here, but thanks so much for your help on everything, Soren! My app is now just about perfect!